# How can I embed my own .mov in to a web page ?

Tags: html, video

I just exported a `.mov` file from Final Cut Pro. 
I want to embed that video into my HTML.
I tried :

```
<object width="800" height="600"
    classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="FRIEND.mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="false">

    <embed src="FRIEND.mov" width="160" height="144"
    autoplay="true" controller="false"
    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
    </embed>

</object>
```

I got :

[image]

Then, I tried :

`<video width="800" height="600" src="FRIEND.mov" controls ></video>`

I got this :

[image]

Then, when I press the `play` btn, I got the sound to play, but not the video. ??? Curious ?

What is the most efficient way to achieve something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can check the video format which are supported by html5 video tag from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp). 
`.mov` format does not have support by any browser.

So you need to do this with `object` tag. At your object tag you are using quicktime player plugin which is not exists on your browser. 
install quick time player plugin to your browser. if you using chrome check [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2445742?hl=en)

Comment: +1 Thank you. I will try to install the plug-in. To make thing a bit easier, do you think I should pre-convert my `.mov` into mp4 then ? What is your thought on that ? Do you recommend it ?

Comment: @rangerover.js it will be better for you. you can play .mp4 files on all browsers with html5 video tag without  any plugin required on browser.